# Clojure Best Practice for Associating a Function with Let

Tags: clojure

I'm defining a function within another function.  Is one of the following approaches better, or more preferred, than the other?

```
(let [hey (println "hey there")] hey)
```

or

```
(let [hey (fn [] (println "hey here"))] (hey))
```

Comment: I assume you meant `#(println ...)` instead of `(println ...)` in the first snippet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version isn't going to work the way you probably want it to. It's evaluated once during the let, and `hey` will get bound to the value `nil`.  i.e. `hey`'s value won't be a function.

The second is fine, and easy to read.  Other approaches:

```
(let [hey0 #(println "hey0")] (hey0))

(letfn [(hey1 [] (println "hey1"))] (hey1))
```

No real rules for their use that I'm aware of.  I use the `#()` reader macro form only for very short functions, and `letfn` if I'm defining a bunch of internal functions together.